# Does Xaml Support countours in space

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, cad, solidworks

When i save a surface with a sketched line from solidworks (see picture) as .XAML [image: Image from solidworks with sketched line]

and use it in WPF the sketched line dissapears.
[image: Image from visual studio wpf without sketched line]

Is this an issue originating from the export from solidworks or from the interpretation in visual studio or does XAML simply not support these sketched lines.

I have included the XAML file below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Viewport3D xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Viewport3D.Camera>
        <OrthographicCamera Position="0.344975,0.237956,0.207745" LookDirection="-0.577382,-0.577288,-0.577382" UpDirection="-0.408204,0.816541,-0.408204" NearPlaneDistance="0.181400" FarPlaneDistance="0.544201" Width="0.362801"/>
    </Viewport3D.Camera>
    <Viewport3D.Children>
        <ModelVisual3D>
            <ModelVisual3D.Transform>
                <RotateTransform3D>
                    <RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                        <AxisAngleRotation3D Angle="0" Axis="0,1,0"/>
                    </RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                </RotateTransform3D>
            </ModelVisual3D.Transform>
            <ModelVisual3D.Children>
                <ModelVisual3D>
                    <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                        <Model3DGroup>
                            <Model3DGroup.Children>
                                <AmbientLight Color="#4C4C4C"/>
                                <DirectionalLight Color="#3B3B3B" Direction="-7.100000,-7.100000,-0.000000"/>
                                <DirectionalLight Color="#222222" Direction="3.400000,-6.100000,7.100000"/>
                                <DirectionalLight Color="#2A2A2A" Direction="9.200000,-3.400000,1.800000"/>
                            </Model3DGroup.Children>
                        </Model3DGroup>
                    </ModelVisual3D.Content>
                </ModelVisual3D>
                <ModelVisual3D>
                    <ModelVisual3D.Transform>
                        <MatrixTransform3D Matrix="1.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 1.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 1.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 1.000000 "/>
                    </ModelVisual3D.Transform>
                    <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                        <Model3DGroup>
                            <Model3DGroup.Children>
                                <GeometryModel3D>
                                    <GeometryModel3D.Material>
                                        <MaterialGroup>
                                            <DiffuseMaterial>
                                                <DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#CAD1EE" Opacity="1.000000"/>
                                                </DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                                            </DiffuseMaterial>
                                            <SpecularMaterial SpecularPower="0.800000">
                                                <SpecularMaterial.Brush>
                                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#A1A7BE" Opacity="1.000000"/>
                                                </SpecularMaterial.Brush>
                                            </SpecularMaterial>
                                        </MaterialGroup>
                                    </GeometryModel3D.Material>
                                    <GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                                        <MeshGeometry3D Positions="0.271000,-0.000579,0.108908 0.271000,-0.000000,0.109723 0.000000,-0.000579,0.108908 0.000000,-0.000000,0.109723 " Normals="0.000000,-0.815134,0.579273 0.000000,-0.815134,0.579273 0.000000,-0.815134,0.579273 0.000000,-0.815134,0.579273 " TriangleIndices="0,1,2 3,2,1 "/>
                                    </GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                                </GeometryModel3D>
                                <GeometryModel3D>
                                    <GeometryModel3D.Material>
                                        <MaterialGroup>
                                            <DiffuseMaterial>
                                                <DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#CAD1EE" Opacity="1.000000"/>
                                                </DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                                            </DiffuseMaterial>
                                            <SpecularMaterial SpecularPower="0.800000">
                                                <SpecularMaterial.Brush>
                                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#A1A7BE" Opacity="1.000000"/>
                                                </SpecularMaterial.Brush>
                                            </SpecularMaterial>
                                        </MaterialGroup>
                                    </GeometryModel3D.Material>
                                    <GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                                        <MeshGeometry3D Positions="0.271000,-0.000119,-0.112369 0.271000,0.000463,-0.113181 0.271000,0.011718,-0.102836 0.271000,0.012388,-0.103579 0.271000,0.022418,-0.092042 0.271000,0.023166,-0.092706 0.271000,0.031846,-0.080121 0.271000,0.032663,-0.080697 0.271000,0.039884,-0.067222 0.271000,0.040761,-0.067703 0.271000,0.046431,-0.053506 0.271000,0.047356,-0.053886 0.271000,0.051407,-0.039146 0.271000,0.052369,-0.039420 0.271000,0.054748,-0.024319 0.271000,0.055735,-0.024484 0.271000,0.056414,-0.009212 0.271000,0.057412,-0.009266 0.271000,0.056382,0.005987 0.271000,0.057380,0.006045 0.271000,0.054654,0.021087 0.271000,0.055640,0.021256 0.271000,0.051251,0.035899 0.271000,0.052212,0.036177 0.271000,0.046216,0.050239 0.271000,0.047139,0.050623 0.271000,0.039611,0.063928 0.271000,0.040486,0.064412 0.271000,0.031520,0.076793 0.271000,0.032335,0.077372 0.271000,0.022042,0.088675 0.271000,0.022788,0.089341 0.271000,0.011298,0.099425 0.271000,0.011965,0.100170 0.271000,-0.000579,0.108908 0.271000,-0.000000,0.109723 " Normals="1.000000,0.000000,0.000000 1.000000,0.000000,0.000000 1.000000,0.000000,0.000000 1.000000,0.000000,0.000000 1.000000,0.000000,0.000000 1.000000,0.000000,0.000000 1.000000,0.000000,0.000000 1.000000,0.000000,0.000000 1.000000,0.000000,0.000000 1.000000,0.000000,0.000000 1.000000,0.000000,0.000000 1.000000,0.000000,0.000000 1.000000,0.000000,0.000000 1.000000,0.000000,0.000000 1.000000,0.000000,0.000000 1.000000,0.000000,0.000000 1.000000,0.000000,0.000000 1.000000,0.000000,0.000000 1.000000,0.000000,0.000000 1.000000,0.000000,0.000000 1.000000,0.000000,0.000000 1.000000,0.000000,0.000000 1.000000,0.000000,0.000000 1.000000,0.000000,0.000000 1.000000,0.000000,0.000000 1.000000,0.000000,0.000000 1.000000,0.000000,0.000000 1.000000,0.000000,0.000000 1.000000,0.000000,0.000000 1.000000,0.000000,0.000000 1.000000,0.000000,0.000000 1.000000,0.000000,0.000000 1.000000,0.000000,0.000000 1.000000,0.000000,0.000000 1.000000,0.000000,0.000000 1.000000,0.000000,0.000000 " TriangleIndices="0,1,2 3,2,1 2,3,4 5,4,3 4,5,6 7,6,5 6,7,8 9,8,7 8,9,10 11,10,9 10,11,12 13,12,11 12,13,14 15,14,13 14,15,16 17,16,15 16,17,18 19,18,17 18,19,20 21,20,19 20,21,22 23,22,21 22,23,24 25,24,23 24,25,26 27,26,25 26,27,28 29,28,27 28,29,30 31,30,29 30,31,32 33,32,31 32,33,34 35,34,33 "/>
                                    </GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                                </GeometryModel3D>
                                <GeometryModel3D>
                                    <GeometryModel3D.Material>
                                        <MaterialGroup>
                                            <DiffuseMaterial>
                                                <DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#CAD1EE" Opacity="1.000000"/>
                                                </DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                                            </DiffuseMaterial>
                                            <SpecularMaterial SpecularPower="0.800000">
                                                <SpecularMaterial.Brush>
                                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#A1A7BE" Opacity="1.000000"/>
                                                </SpecularMaterial.Brush>
                                            </SpecularMaterial>
                                        </MaterialGroup>
                                    </GeometryModel3D.Material>
                                    <GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                                        <MeshGeometry3D Positions="0.271000,0.000463,-0.113181 0.000000,0.000463,-0.113181 0.000000,0.012388,-0.103579 0.271000,0.000463,-0.113181 0.000000,0.012388,-0.103579 0.271000,0.012388,-0.103579 0.000000,0.023166,-0.092706 0.271000,0.023166,-0.092706 0.000000,0.032663,-0.080697 0.271000,0.032663,-0.080697 0.000000,0.040761,-0.067703 0.271000,0.040761,-0.067703 0.000000,0.047356,-0.053886 0.271000,0.047356,-0.053886 0.000000,0.052369,-0.039420 0.271000,0.052369,-0.039420 0.000000,0.055735,-0.024484 0.271000,0.055735,-0.024484 0.000000,0.057412,-0.009266 0.271000,0.057412,-0.009266 0.000000,0.057380,0.006045 0.271000,0.057380,0.006045 0.000000,0.055640,0.021256 0.271000,0.055640,0.021256 0.000000,0.052212,0.036177 0.271000,0.052212,0.036177 0.000000,0.047139,0.050623 0.271000,0.047139,0.050623 0.000000,0.040486,0.064412 0.271000,0.040486,0.064412 0.000000,0.032335,0.077372 0.271000,0.032335,0.077372 0.000000,0.022788,0.089341 0.271000,0.022788,0.089341 0.000000,0.011965,0.100170 0.271000,0.011965,0.100170 0.000000,-0.000000,0.109723 0.271000,-0.000000,0.109723 " Normals="0.000000,0.582657,-0.812718 0.000000,0.582657,-0.812718 0.000000,0.669743,-0.742593 0.000000,0.582657,-0.812718 0.000000,0.669743,-0.742593 0.000000,0.669743,-0.742593 0.000000,0.748456,-0.663185 0.000000,0.748456,-0.663185 0.000000,0.817812,-0.575485 0.000000,0.817812,-0.575485 0.000000,0.876945,-0.480592 0.000000,0.876945,-0.480592 0.000000,0.925114,-0.379690 0.000000,0.925114,-0.379690 0.000000,0.961718,-0.274041 0.000000,0.961718,-0.274041 0.000000,0.986299,-0.164967 0.000000,0.986299,-0.164967 0.000000,0.998550,-0.053830 0.000000,0.998550,-0.053830 0.000000,0.998318,0.057980 0.000000,0.998318,0.057980 0.000000,0.985605,0.169065 0.000000,0.985605,0.169065 0.000000,0.960571,0.278037 0.000000,0.960571,0.278037 0.000000,0.923528,0.383532 0.000000,0.923528,0.383532 0.000000,0.874939,0.484233 0.000000,0.874939,0.484233 0.000000,0.815413,0.578880 0.000000,0.815413,0.578880 0.000000,0.745692,0.666290 0.000000,0.745692,0.666290 0.000000,0.666650,0.745371 0.000000,0.666650,0.745371 0.000000,0.579273,0.815134 0.000000,0.579273,0.815134 " TriangleIndices="0,1,2 3,4,5 6,5,4 5,6,7 8,7,6 7,8,9 10,9,8 9,10,11 12,11,10 11,12,13 14,13,12 13,14,15 16,15,14 15,16,17 18,17,16 17,18,19 20,19,18 19,20,21 22,21,20 21,22,23 24,23,22 23,24,25 26,25,24 25,26,27 28,27,26 27,28,29 30,29,28 29,30,31 32,31,30 31,32,33 34,33,32 33,34,35 36,35,34 35,36,37 "/>
                                    </GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                                </GeometryModel3D>
                                <GeometryModel3D>
                                    <GeometryModel3D.Material>
                                        <MaterialGroup>
                                            <DiffuseMaterial>
                                                <DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#CAD1EE" Opacity="1.000000"/>
                                                </DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                                            </DiffuseMaterial>
                                            <SpecularMaterial SpecularPower="0.800000">
                                                <SpecularMaterial.Brush>
                                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#A1A7BE" Opacity="1.000000"/>
                                                </SpecularMaterial.Brush>
                                            </SpecularMaterial>
                                        </MaterialGroup>
                                    </GeometryModel3D.Material>
                                    <GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                                        <MeshGeometry3D Positions="0.271000,-0.000579,0.108908 0.000000,-0.000579,0.108908 0.000000,0.011298,0.099425 0.271000,-0.000579,0.108908 0.000000,0.011298,0.099425 0.271000,0.011298,0.099425 0.000000,0.022042,0.088675 0.271000,0.022042,0.088675 0.000000,0.031520,0.076793 0.271000,0.031520,0.076793 0.000000,0.039611,0.063928 0.271000,0.039611,0.063928 0.000000,0.046216,0.050239 0.271000,0.046216,0.050239 0.000000,0.051251,0.035899 0.271000,0.051251,0.035899 0.000000,0.054654,0.021087 0.271000,0.054654,0.021087 0.000000,0.056382,0.005987 0.271000,0.056382,0.005987 0.000000,0.056414,-0.009212 0.271000,0.056414,-0.009212 0.000000,0.054748,-0.024319 0.271000,0.054748,-0.024319 0.000000,0.051407,-0.039146 0.271000,0.051407,-0.039146 0.000000,0.046431,-0.053506 0.271000,0.046431,-0.053506 0.000000,0.039884,-0.067222 0.271000,0.039884,-0.067222 0.000000,0.031846,-0.080121 0.271000,0.031846,-0.080121 0.000000,0.022418,-0.092042 0.271000,0.022418,-0.092042 0.000000,0.011718,-0.102836 0.271000,0.011718,-0.102836 0.000000,-0.000119,-0.112369 0.271000,-0.000119,-0.112369 " Normals="0.000000,-0.579273,-0.815134 0.000000,-0.579273,-0.815134 0.000000,-0.666650,-0.745371 0.000000,-0.579273,-0.815134 0.000000,-0.666650,-0.745371 0.000000,-0.666650,-0.745371 0.000000,-0.745692,-0.666290 0.000000,-0.745692,-0.666290 0.000000,-0.815413,-0.578880 0.000000,-0.815413,-0.578880 0.000000,-0.874939,-0.484233 0.000000,-0.874939,-0.484233 0.000000,-0.923528,-0.383532 0.000000,-0.923528,-0.383532 0.000000,-0.960571,-0.278037 0.000000,-0.960571,-0.278037 0.000000,-0.985605,-0.169065 0.000000,-0.985605,-0.169065 0.000000,-0.998318,-0.057980 0.000000,-0.998318,-0.057980 0.000000,-0.998550,0.053830 0.000000,-0.998550,0.053830 0.000000,-0.986299,0.164967 0.000000,-0.986299,0.164967 0.000000,-0.961718,0.274041 0.000000,-0.961718,0.274041 0.000000,-0.925114,0.379690 0.000000,-0.925114,0.379690 0.000000,-0.876945,0.480592 0.000000,-0.876945,0.480592 0.000000,-0.817812,0.575485 0.000000,-0.817812,0.575485 0.000000,-0.748456,0.663185 0.000000,-0.748456,0.663185 0.000000,-0.669743,0.742593 0.000000,-0.669743,0.742593 0.000000,-0.582657,0.812718 0.000000,-0.582657,0.812718 " TriangleIndices="0,1,2 3,4,5 6,5,4 5,6,7 8,7,6 7,8,9 10,9,8 9,10,11 12,11,10 11,12,13 14,13,12 13,14,15 16,15,14 15,16,17 18,17,16 17,18,19 20,19,18 19,20,21 22,21,20 21,22,23 24,23,22 23,24,25 26,25,24 25,26,27 28,27,26 27,28,29 30,29,28 29,30,31 32,31,30 31,32,33 34,33,32 33,34,35 36,35,34 35,36,37 "/>
                                    </GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                                </GeometryModel3D>
                                <GeometryModel3D>
                                    <GeometryModel3D.Material>
                                        <MaterialGroup>
                                            <DiffuseMaterial>
                                                <DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#CAD1EE" Opacity="1.000000"/>
                                                </DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                                            </DiffuseMaterial>
                                            <SpecularMaterial SpecularPower="0.800000">
                                                <SpecularMaterial.Brush>
                                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#A1A7BE" Opacity="1.000000"/>
                                                </SpecularMaterial.Brush>
                                            </SpecularMaterial>
                                        </MaterialGroup>
                                    </GeometryModel3D.Material>
                                    <GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                                        <MeshGeometry3D Positions="0.271000,0.000463,-0.113181 0.271000,-0.000119,-0.112369 0.000000,0.000463,-0.113181 0.000000,-0.000119,-0.112369 " Normals="0.000000,-0.812718,-0.582657 0.000000,-0.812718,-0.582657 0.000000,-0.812718,-0.582657 0.000000,-0.812718,-0.582657 " TriangleIndices="0,1,2 3,2,1 "/>
                                    </GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                                </GeometryModel3D>
                                <GeometryModel3D>
                                    <GeometryModel3D.Material>
                                        <MaterialGroup>
                                            <DiffuseMaterial>
                                                <DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#CAD1EE" Opacity="1.000000"/>
                                                </DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                                            </DiffuseMaterial>
                                            <SpecularMaterial SpecularPower="0.800000">
                                                <SpecularMaterial.Brush>
                                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#A1A7BE" Opacity="1.000000"/>
                                                </SpecularMaterial.Brush>
                                            </SpecularMaterial>
                                        </MaterialGroup>
                                    </GeometryModel3D.Material>
                                    <GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                                        <MeshGeometry3D Positions="0.000000,-0.000579,0.108908 0.000000,-0.000000,0.109723 0.000000,0.011298,0.099425 0.000000,0.011965,0.100170 0.000000,0.022042,0.088675 0.000000,0.022788,0.089341 0.000000,0.031520,0.076793 0.000000,0.032335,0.077372 0.000000,0.039611,0.063928 0.000000,0.040486,0.064412 0.000000,0.046216,0.050239 0.000000,0.047139,0.050623 0.000000,0.051251,0.035899 0.000000,0.052212,0.036177 0.000000,0.054654,0.021087 0.000000,0.055640,0.021256 0.000000,0.056382,0.005987 0.000000,0.057380,0.006045 0.000000,0.056414,-0.009212 0.000000,0.057412,-0.009266 0.000000,0.054748,-0.024319 0.000000,0.055735,-0.024484 0.000000,0.051407,-0.039146 0.000000,0.052369,-0.039420 0.000000,0.046431,-0.053506 0.000000,0.047356,-0.053886 0.000000,0.039884,-0.067222 0.000000,0.040761,-0.067703 0.000000,0.031846,-0.080121 0.000000,0.032663,-0.080697 0.000000,0.022418,-0.092042 0.000000,0.023166,-0.092706 0.000000,0.011718,-0.102836 0.000000,0.012388,-0.103579 0.000000,-0.000119,-0.112369 0.000000,0.000463,-0.113181 " Normals="-1.000000,0.000000,0.000000 -1.000000,0.000000,0.000000 -1.000000,0.000000,0.000000 -1.000000,0.000000,0.000000 -1.000000,0.000000,0.000000 -1.000000,0.000000,0.000000 -1.000000,0.000000,0.000000 -1.000000,0.000000,0.000000 -1.000000,0.000000,0.000000 -1.000000,0.000000,0.000000 -1.000000,0.000000,0.000000 -1.000000,0.000000,0.000000 -1.000000,0.000000,0.000000 -1.000000,0.000000,0.000000 -1.000000,0.000000,0.000000 -1.000000,0.000000,0.000000 -1.000000,0.000000,0.000000 -1.000000,0.000000,0.000000 -1.000000,0.000000,0.000000 -1.000000,0.000000,0.000000 -1.000000,0.000000,0.000000 -1.000000,0.000000,0.000000 -1.000000,0.000000,0.000000 -1.000000,0.000000,0.000000 -1.000000,0.000000,0.000000 -1.000000,0.000000,0.000000 -1.000000,0.000000,0.000000 -1.000000,0.000000,0.000000 -1.000000,0.000000,0.000000 -1.000000,0.000000,0.000000 -1.000000,0.000000,0.000000 -1.000000,0.000000,0.000000 -1.000000,0.000000,0.000000 -1.000000,0.000000,0.000000 -1.000000,0.000000,0.000000 -1.000000,0.000000,0.000000 " TriangleIndices="0,1,2 3,2,1 2,3,4 5,4,3 4,5,6 7,6,5 6,7,8 9,8,7 8,9,10 11,10,9 10,11,12 13,12,11 12,13,14 15,14,13 14,15,16 17,16,15 16,17,18 19,18,17 18,19,20 21,20,19 20,21,22 23,22,21 22,23,24 25,24,23 24,25,26 27,26,25 26,27,28 29,28,27 28,29,30 31,30,29 30,31,32 33,32,31 32,33,34 35,34,33 "/>
                                    </GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                                </GeometryModel3D>
                            </Model3DGroup.Children>
                        </Model3DGroup>
                    </ModelVisual3D.Content>
                    <ModelVisual3D.Children/>
                </ModelVisual3D>
            </ModelVisual3D.Children>
        </ModelVisual3D>
    </Viewport3D.Children>
</Viewport3D>
```

Comment: It would seem that the sketched line is not the only part of the drawing that has changed.